# How to Draw a Label in ListView client area

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

When there is no data to show in ListView, it is better to show message as "no data is changed now", which should be drawed in a TLabel.
How to draw a TLabel in the ListView client area?

Comment: Remy has given you an excellent answer that deserves to be accepted. Please can you do so.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a `TLabel` for that.

On Vista and later, you can subclass the ListView to handle the [`LVN_GETEMPTYMARKUP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb774833) notification.

```pascal
uses
  ..., CommCtrl;

private
  PrevWndProc: TWndMethod;

procedure TMyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PrevWndProc := ListView.WndProc;
  ListView.WndProc := ListViewWndProc;
end;

procedure TMyForm.ListViewWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg = CN_NOTIFY then
  begin
    if TWMNotifyLV(Message).NMHdr.code = LVN_GETEMPTYMARKUP then
    begin
      with PNMLVEmptyMarkup(TWMNotifyLV(Message).NMHdr)^ do
      begin
        dwFlags := EMF_CENTERED;
        StrLCopy(szMarkup, 'My message here', L_MAX_URL_LENGTH);
      end;
      Message.Result := 1;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  PrevWndProc(Message);
end;
```

The downside is you have little control over where the text appears (only whether it is left-justified or centered) or how it is formatted, and you cannot change the text dynamically (you would have to add at least one item and then remove it to trigger a new notification).

On earlier versions, or if you need more control over the text position/format/behavior, you can use the ListView's `OnCustomDraw` event instead.  You can draw whatever you want on the ListView's `Canvas` within the area designated by a `TRect` provided by the event.  If needed, you can use [`ListView_GetHeader()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761290.aspx) to determine if the ListView's column headers are visible, and if so then use `GetWindowRect()` to get the header's height so you can subtract it from the top of the `TRect` before drawing.

For example:

```pascal
procedure TMyForm.ListViewCustomDraw(Sender: TCustomListView; const ARect: TRect; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
var
  R, Temp: TRect;
  Wnd: HWND;
begin
  if Sender.Items.Count <= 0 then
  begin
    R := ARect;
    Wnd := ListView_GetHeader(Sender.Handle);
    if Wnd <> 0 then  
    begin
      GetWindowRect(Wnd, @Temp);
      R.Top := R.Top + (Temp.Bottom-Temp.Top);
    end;
    R.Top := R.Top + 10;
    DrawText(Sender.Canvas.Handle, 'My message here', -1, @R, DT_CENTER or DT_SINGLELINE);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have tried the second method, it's good!
GetWindowRect(Wnd, @Temp); should changed to GetWindowRect(Wnd, Temp);, so as to the parameter of DrawText.

Comment: There is another problem.  I use OnCustomDraw event to draw a text "This is a empty list".  I create a button to clear the listView. After all the items are cleared, "This is.." text is showed. Then I added a new item row immedially, but the text is not cleaned. So the short row and "This is a empty list" show at same time.

Comment: After calling listview.Repaint, text "This is an empty list" is removed.

Comment: You can use `Invalidate()` or `Repaint()`, but yes, when you add an item, you may need to trigger a redraw.  I usually use this technique with virtual ListViews, and [`ListView_SetItemCount()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775093.aspx) triggers a repaint.